# Automatically convert \left to \Bigl

Tags: macros, input

I have a LaTeX file, which includes tons of other auto-generated LaTeX files containing TikZ figures. Suppose I want to make every `\left(` in the TikZ figure appear at the same, fixed size, say `\Bigl(`.

It's not impossible to change the auto-generator side, but I'd like to solve the problem on the side which includes the figures.

I tried

```
\def\includetikzfile{#1}{{\let\left\Bigl\input{#1.tikz}}}
```

but it quickly went to an infinite loop, exceeding the TeX capacity.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's easy to see where the loop comes from as `\Bigr` is defined in terms of `\Big` which is (by default)

```
\def\Big#1{{\hbox{$\left#1\vbox to11.5\p@{}\right.\n@space$}}}
```

so defined in terms of `\left`

It is probably safer just to do a replace/edit on the incoming file

If you wanted to do this in TeX you'd neeed

```
\let\oldleft\left
\let\oldright\right
```

and then redefine each of these

```
\def\big#1{{\hbox{$\left#1\vbox to8.5\p@{}\right.\n@space$}}}
\def\Big#1{{\hbox{$\left#1\vbox to11.5\p@{}\right.\n@space$}}}
\def\bigg#1{{\hbox{$\left#1\vbox to14.5\p@{}\right.\n@space$}}}
\def\Bigg#1{{\hbox{$\left#1\vbox to17.5\p@{}\right.\n@space$}}}
```

to use `\oldleft` and `\oldright` then you would be slightly safer to do

```
\let\left\Bigl
\let\right\Bigr
```

in your local redefinition, although there can still be cases that fail, notably as the `\left` and `\right` primitives do not scan for arguments the same way as macros like `\Bigr` so for example

```
$\left\delimiter"26A30C  \frac{a}{b} \right.$
```

is OK but if you replace `\left` with `\Bigr` you get

```
$\Bigl\delimiter"26A30C  \frac{a}{b} \Bigr.$
```

which produces

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \vbox 
l.11 $\Bigl\delimiter
```

as the argument to `\Bigr` is just the token `\delimiter` not the full delimiter specification.

Comment: Thanks for the ellaboration about drawbacks due to `\left` being primitive!

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do the redefinition of `\big` etc automatically? I guess I should ask it as a separate question, as is customary in Stack Exchange...